# Joda-Time: как привести к виду дату 2018-05-08T10:41:52+0000

Tags: java, android-studio, kotlin, jodatime

```
val dateTime = DateTime.parse("$mYear-$mMonth-$mDay $hourOfDay:$minute", DateTimeFormat.forPattern("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm"))
```

Результат: `2018-06-27T09:58:00.000+07:00`

Нужно получить такой тип. `2018-05-08T10:41:52+0000`

Comment: вы хотите перевести часовой пояс из +7 в 0 ? или прыгнуть в прошлое? можете уточнять что именно вы хотите, а то по 2 разным дням и времени сложно понять

Comment: @Wlad мне сервер возвращает в таком формате `2018-06-16T10:41:53+0000`, я ему в таком же формате должен вернуть дату. Двоеточие мешает. А даты для примера приведены. Перевести из +7 в 0 нужно.

Comment: уточните откуда берется "Результат: 2018-06-27T09:58:00.000+07:00"

Comment: @Ramiz в функции DateTime.parse() один из аргументов принимает строку, а второй шаблон. Строка формируется из DateTimePicker. Вот результат исходя из этого получается.

Comment: @nuqss понятно, т.е. это стандартный toString от DateTime

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
dateTime.toString("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ")
```

один Z дает часовой пояс без двоеточия:

> [Zone: 'Z' outputs offset without a colon, 'ZZ' outputs the offset with a colon, 'ZZZ' or more outputs the zone id.](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/apidocs/org/joda/time/format/DateTimeFormat.html)

Comment: Ваше решение подтолкнуло к решению моей задачи, ответ - `dateTime.toString("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZ")`.

Comment: Разумно посмотреть форматы `strftime` в С, кажеться на ней все DateTime и построены. `"%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S%Ez"` формат для такой строки времени